# How to create header numbers with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using this very formulaic CSS to try to add header numbers to an HTML5 document.  Sadly, it's producing an undesirable output.  How can I get it to do what I mean?

```
$> CSS
h1 { counter-reset: c2; font-size: 2.0em; }
h2 { counter-reset: c3; font-size: 1.8em; }
h3 { counter-reset: c4; font-size: 1.6em; }
h4 { counter-reset: c5; font-size: 1.4em; }
h5 { counter-reset: c6; font-size: 1.2em; }
h6 { counter-reset: c7; font-size: 1.0em; }
h7 { counter-reset: c8; font-size: 0.9em; }
h8 { counter-reset: c9; font-size: 0.8em; }
h9 {                    font-size: 0.7em; }

h1:before {counter-increment: c1; content: counter(c1) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h2:before {counter-increment: c2; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h3:before {counter-increment: c3; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h4:before {counter-increment: c4; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) "." counter(c4) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h5:before {counter-increment: c5; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) "." counter(c4) "." counter(c5) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h6:before {counter-increment: c6; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) "." counter(c4) "." counter(c5) "." counter(c6) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h7:before {counter-increment: c7; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) "." counter(c4) "." counter(c5) "." counter(c6) "." counter(c7) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h8:before {counter-increment: c8; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) "." counter(c4) "." counter(c5) "." counter(c6) "." counter(c7) "." counter(c8) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
h9:before {counter-increment: c9; content: counter(c1) "." counter(c2) "." counter(c3) "." counter(c4) "." counter(c5) "." counter(c6) "." counter(c7) "." counter(c8) "." counter(c9) ".\0000a0\0000a0"}
```

The output looks like this:

## 1. Text

## 1. Text

### 0.1 Text

### 0.2 Text

#### 0.2.1 Text

and so on.  Why is counter(c1) resetting back to 0 and not incrementing?

Comment: try initializing `c1` as in `body { counter-reset: c1; }`.

Comment: @torazaburo: That worked.  Marked the answer below as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following style rule will solve your problem (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bzh2rt4/)):

```
body { counter-reset: c1; }
```

---

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters):

> To use a CSS counter, it must first be reset to a value, 0 by default.

The relevant part from the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#scope) explains why your counter is reset to zero. The call to `content: counter(c1)` is not in scope of any call to `counter-reset: c1`. As per the specification:

> If 'counter-increment' or 'content' on an element or pseudo-element
>   refers to a counter that is not in the scope of any 'counter-reset',
>   implementations should behave as though a 'counter-reset' had reset
>   the counter to 0 on that element or pseudo-element.